# perl regex on multiple line

Tags: regex, perl

I 've never done perl in my life and a few regex. But i need to debug a perl file that read function reference that could be on multiple line. 
Indeed I got this type of regex :

```
my @m = ($content =~ /.*\s*function\s*\((\w+)\s*\,\s*(\w+)\s*\)\;.*/ig)
```

where `$content` is my multiple line string (in fact a file content). But I don't understand why I only match pattern like this

```
function(param1,param2);
```

And I don't match if there is a line break after the comma. The following function isn't recognized.

```
function(param1,
          param2);
```

My Code is like that:

```
open (FILE, "myfile") or die "Trouble opening the file";
    my $content; 
    local $/;
    $content=<FILE>;
    my @m;
    @m = ($content =~ /\s*function\s*\((\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\)\;/gi);
    foreach (@m) {
       print "$_\n";
    }
```

BTW sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Yes But how can i do if i don't want to modify (in fact i want to read $1 and $2 that will store param1 and param2) how can i do it .

Comment: When I use it, i only match the last function and the others (which i was detecting before desapear). I don't understand the behave. I think it goes greedy. How can I avoid that.

Comment: Try removing the first and last `.*`, or, to keep the behavior closer to what is was, use instead `[^\n]*`. (while keeping `/s` modifier as suggested by zdim)

Comment: Ok thank you for your help any way.

Comment: Hello Dada, i remove both `.*` and i get the same behave as when I wasn't using `s` modifier.

Comment: I suspect your problem isn't related to `.*` and the s modifier. Are you sure that the parameters only contain word characters? Are you sure that your script doesn't read the content by line? Show the whole part of the code that read the file and tests the pattern and your real string.

Comment: @zdim `\s` always matches newlines. The `/s` modifier only affects `.`.

Comment: I edited my post to show the structure of my source.

Comment: @GuillaumeMILAN: can't reproduce the problem: https://eval.in/841102. That's why you need to **show your real string**.

Comment: @melpomene  Ugh, of course.  I should learn to back off when too tired.  Thank you, removed that #%^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in comments, remove `.*`, you may also remove the unnecessary escapes:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my $content = <<EOD;
function(param11,param12);
function(param21,
          param22);
function
(param31 
,
param32
);
EOD
my @m = ($content =~ /function\s*\((\w+)\s*,\s*(\w+)\s*\);/ig);
say Dumper\@m;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'param11',
          'param12',
          'param21',
          'param22',
          'param31',
          'param32'
        ];
```

Comment: My mind just blow up. I do the same as you and it works for function but when i do it in my code I have trouble. Will come back when I will find the difference.

Comment: Ok found that the actual code used object param with dot. And dot isn't taken in consideration by `(\w+)`. And the function on multiple line were using these objects. NO LUCK AT ALL

Comment: @GuillaumeMILAN: use `[\w.]` instead of `\w`

Comment: finnaly fixed it. I used ([0-9a-zA-Z_\.]+). Maybe there is something simpler but it works.

Comment: @GuillaumeMILAN: `[\w.]` is the same than `[0-9a-zA-Z_\.]`